# Can I make a Java applet ignore/passthrough Command+Q on a Mac?

Tags: java, macos, command-line, applet, command

This question is a bit odd, but I'm using a KVM over IP client that is run as a Java applet. When I press Command+Q the local Java applet running on OS X intercepts the command and shuts down the the applet, terminating my KVM session. I would like to be able to send this command and have the applet ignore it (as a command) but still pass it through so that the program running in the KVM session sees and responds to the command. Does anyone know of any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it is impossible. The Mac OS will trap the Command-Q shortcut unless you tell it not to, which can only be done with native methods, which can not be used in applets.